# OWIN ADFS not returning SecurityToken

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, token, owin, saml, adfs2.0

Im trying to generate an ActAs token for another adfs, but the first ADFS i login doesnt return me the SecurityToken.
Am i missing some configuration on OWIN Startup?

Startup.cs

```csharp
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                AuthenticationType = WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {                        
                    SaveSigninToken = true,
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],

                },

                Configuration = getWsFederationConfiguration()
            }
        );
    }

    private static WsFederationConfiguration getWsFederationConfiguration()
    {
        WsFederationConfiguration configuration = new WsFederationConfiguration
        {
            Issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederation:trustedIssuer"],
            TokenEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederation:issuer"],
        };

        configuration.SigningKeys.Add(new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wsFederation:trustedIssuerSigningKey"]))));

        return configuration;
    }
```

How i retrieve the token:

```csharp
  public SecurityToken GetSecuritySAMLToken()
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal icp = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)icp.Identity;
        BootstrapContext bootstrapContext = claimsIdentity.BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext;

        //bootstrapContext is not null and bootstrapContext.Token is not null, however bootstrapContext.SecurityToken is null
        return bootstrapContext.SecurityToken;
    }
```

**UPDATE 1**

Tried converting string(SAMLToken) to SecurityToken, handler.ReadToken returns null.

```
  public SecurityToken GetSecuritySAMLToken()
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal icp = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)icp.Identity;
        BootstrapContext bootstrapContext = claimsIdentity.BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext;

        return GetSecurityTokenFromStringToken(bootstrapContext);
    }

    private static SecurityToken GetSecurityTokenFromStringToken(BootstrapContext bootstrapContext)
    {
        var handler = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection();
        SecurityToken ST = handler.ReadToken(bootstrapContext.Token);
        return ST;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to retrive it this way:

```
 private static SecurityToken GetSecurityTokenFromStringToken(BootstrapContext bootstrapContext)
    {
        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler handler = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler();
        handler.Configuration = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration();
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(bootstrapContext.Token));
        SecurityToken samlToken = handler.ReadToken(reader);

        return samlToken;
    }
```